# INF installation file for upper device filter driver

Tags: windows, filter, driver

I'm trying to develop a filter device for disk encryption. For this I designed an upper device filter driver (attached above partmgr) based on diskperf WDK sample.
     * I succesfully installed (inf file) my filter driver as an upper class filter driver (based on diskperf WDK sample) but did not really understand how to install it for a particular device. If someone could help me on this or post some links to documented samples (example what to use HKLM, HKR, and so on...) it would be great.

Many thanks for your answer,
best regards,
Jerome.

Answer (score 2):

Also check addfilter utility in Windows DDK (%DDK_ROOT%\src\storage\filters\addfilter), it shows how to install lower or upper filter drivers for a particular device using setup api.

There's also an article on MSDN describing difference between installing device-specific and class filter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547595%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The omnipresent Hitachi `cfadisk.sys` "sample" at:

http://www.getusb.info/usb-hack-turn-a-usb-stick-into-a-hard-drive-or-local-disk/

shows how to install a filter driver for a particular device. (Use `UpperFilters` instead of `LowerFilters` in the .inf file).